Reducing high radon levels near sump pump
Radon levels near the sump pump are up to 5 times higher than levels measured elsewhere in the basement.
Reducing levels at this major source should reduce them everywhere.
It feels like it would be simpler and more efficient to install a dedicated heat-recovery-ventilator with its indoor intake near the sump pump.

Is there any reason that having an HRV integrated with the existing HVAC furnace ducts would be a better idea?
With a dedicated system, what would be the best way to vent the indoor air output?


I'm not sure I understand. Why not a sealed sump lid with a conventional Radon mitigation fan and duct? By comparison, an HRV is a sloppy way to remove Radon that's already in the air, whereas a proper removal mechanism prevents that in the first place.

Do not know what containment needed for radon, but a HRV slows down air passage, so it seems to defeat the purpose of venting radon out of the house, if radon is not contained by the HRV.

“It would be simpler” - than what? You may be thinking of something but you didn’t write it and we can’t read your mind.

@nobody — I meant simpler than an HRV that's integrated with the existing HVAC, and more efficient because the air being removed would have much more concentrated levels.

Stock standard solution is a sealed sump cover, and a radon fan (fan placed above the inhabited area or outside, so any leaks in the living space suck inwards) and vented above roofline. A fairly large pipe either needs to run inside up through the roof, or outside and then up above the roof.
An HRV won't really do the same job - the fan specs are rather different. It also won't meet the standards for a radon reduction system, even if it manages to somewhat reduce the radon (which ventilation will help with.)
If you're willing to DIY doing a radon system right is not all that difficult or expensive (shop with care, of course, rather than getting taken by the first site you find.)
